# Application icon is not updating in device Settings when trying to upgrade?

Tags: android, android-settings

I am having two version of my app, i.e Test v1.0 and TestApp v2.0. Both have its own app icon and app name.

I observed that after successful upgrade (install v2.0 on v1.0), the application name and app logo does not change in Setting-Application screen.

It shows the old version details (like v1.0 with TestApp name), except version no.

Current version details appear after doing "Force stop".

This things usually misguide the user to know the current app version.

How do I refresh setting- Application screen after app upgrade?

Go to **device's Settings Screen -> Applications > App info**

**Here Application new App icon not updated sometimes and referring the old icon.**

Answer (score 0):

The app in the app launcher (Home screen) should be updated, but the shortcuts won't be updated until the next refresh of the `homescreen`. The `homescreen` does refresh itself once in a while, so the new icon will eventually replace the old icon automatically on refresh. 
 on another note,Android used to store app cache for your version code. if nothing helps, you need to wipe out app cache on install

Comment: okay...Android used to store app cache for your version code. if nothing helps, you need to wipe out app cache on install. this is True ! But any specific reason to resolved this rather than wipe out app cache on install.

Comment: You can not refresh the home-screen in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the settings from the recents stack it should update afterwards.  It looks like google is using a image cache and its not getting updated until the settings process is stopped.  you can do this but if your desperate:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.android.settings");
```

You'll need a try catch around it and hold the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

if the settings is opened it should get killed and restart immediately updating the icon.